# How can I force an image to maintain aspect ratio in WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, xaml

I have an image in a WPF window. When I resize the window the image resizes with it. Is it possible to preserve the aspect ratio when the image is resizing, so it doesn't look squashed if the window is too narrow? If so, how?

Comment: The default value for [`Image.Stretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx) is `Uniform`, so that would not be happening by default. That means you are specifically doing something to override it. And you don't show what it is you are doing.

Comment: Can you show your XAML please?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Set the [`Image.Stretch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms605067.aspx) Property to `Uniform`

```
<Image Stretch="Uniform" ....etc />
```